# Mongodb aggregation pipeline stages

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation of say 4 stages match,lookup, unwind, project as mentioned in the same order.

Suppose if the resultant data from the match stage is null that is it does not return any document then does the aggregation breaks?  or it passes null data to next stage and executes all the next stages?

If it executes all the next stage then how to break the aggregation when the result of match query is null.

I am asking this so that i can minimise the query to the database.

Comment: Yes sure the below answer was helpful 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, if it is null, it will execute the stages and returns empty result. You don't need to break it if it is null.

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9XxQMTPJtxG)

> The MongoDB aggregation pipeline consists of stages. Each stage transforms the documents as they pass through the pipeline.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

Explanation:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   { $match: { status: "A" } },
   { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$amount" } } }
])
```

First Stage: The $match stage filters the documents by the status field and passes to the next stage those documents that have status equal to "A".

Second Stage: The $group stage groups the documents by the cust_id field to calculate the sum of the amount for each unique cust_id.

Comment: I now understood that no mater what the result of the stage the next stages will execute. My question is that suppose if in the match stage no document is returned then can i break the next stage in the aggregation. see if i breaks the stages then number of query to the database will be minimized hence can i do this?

Comment: I don't think you can break it in between. Let's say you have three pipelines, one is match, other two are groups. Match returns 10 documents. First group tries to group on field x which is not there in 10 documents. Other tries the grouping on field y which is there in those 10 documents. So first group returns empty and second group performs the operation. Hope you understand.

Comment: One would expect a stage to be very fast to execute on an empty result set. Don't worry about it.